# ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources.extern.six.moves'; 'pkg_resources.extern.six' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, archlinux

I can not import pkg_resources. Whenever I tried it shows

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jun 28 2016, 08:46:01) 
[GCC 6.1.1 20160602] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import pkg_resources
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
      from pkg_resources.extern.six.moves import urllib, map, filter
ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources.extern.six.moves'; 'pkg_resources.extern.six' is not a package
```

Is `from pkg_resources` referring  to  `/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/extern`  (in which there is no six package). Can you point out what I am doing wrong?

I am using Arch Linux,  Python 3.5.2

Comment: can you please post your code ...I think there might be importing issue. Cause its working fine for me.

Comment: @RohitSalunke Sorry didn't get you. I don't have any code. I just cant  import pkg_resources in python3 console.

Comment: ok there might be problem in python lib. try running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-pkg-resources`. In my case `import pkg_resources` is working properly.

Comment: already reinstalled python-setuptools using pacman (package manger in arch). pkg-resources will come under setup tools. Right?

Comment: Yeh...bro if u followed python-setup tools that was enough to get pkg-resources. Sorry cant predict this why its stuck up there.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is no `six` package there.  `six` is just a name defined in

```
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py
```

To be exact, it looks as follows:

```
names = 'packaging', 'pyparsing', 'six'
VendorImporter(__name__, names).install()
```

But `VendorImporter` is a rather uncommon piece of `python`, it is part of `setuptools` therefore it can be expected, I guess.  In simple words it performs the import from:

```
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py
```

Which does contain `moves` alright:

```
_MovedItems._moved_attributes = _moved_attributes

moves = _MovedItems(__name__ + ".moves")
_importer._add_module(moves, "moves")
```

---

Now let's see how `pacman` deals with that:

```
# pacman -Qo /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py is owned by python-setuptools 1:25.1.3-1
```

Right, `extern/__init__.py` is owned by `setuptools`, that is what we expected.  Now

```
# pacman -Qo /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py is owned by python-six 1.10.0-2
```

We see that `six` is part of `python-six`.

So, we discovered that `python-setuptools` is dependent on `python-six`.  The [`python-setuptools` dependency chain](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/python-setuptools/) is therefore incorrect since it does not list `python-six`, that is something that happens sometimes with package managers (not only `pacman` but all package managers suffer from problems with dependency chains from time to time).

For the problem at hand, you need to install `python-six` manually, and `python-setuptools` will then work as expected:

```
pacman -S python-six
```